# Stuck on the parse.com getting started guide

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm trying to follow the guid on: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/php

I complete the composer install, create the composer.json file and install the SDK as described in the guide.

The next step is a mystery to me: "Require the autoload.php file, and initialize Parse:" What does this mean? Do I create a file and put the code in it? What should the file be called? Where should it be located? How to I run it?

The "guide" doesn't explain what I'm actually supposed to do!?

Answer (score 1):

It does, it's the lines of code directly below that.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;

ParseClient::initialize('APPLICATION ID', 'REST API KEY', 'MASTER KEY');
```

Put it wherever you want, call it whatever you want.

Comment: doesn't the index.php have to be a specific location relative to the project folder?

Comment: There's nothing in the tutorial that indicates that. If you're using a framework you need to follow it's rules. You don't even have to call it index.php.

Comment: I'm not using and I don't want to use a framework. I'm not doing anything complex. I just want to create a simple index.php file and host it at e.g. [myapp].parseapp.com/index.php

Comment: Wait are you saying you want Parse to host your file? That's not the same as using their SDK. Do they even host code?

Comment: I quote from https://parse.com/docs/php/guide

Comment: The Parse platform provides a complete backend solution for your mobile application. Generally, our goal is to eliminate the need for managing servers and writing server-side code. Our PHP SDK is for those applications and situations where server-side code is necessary, or simply prefered.

Comment: If its a complete backend solution surely that include hosting?

Comment: @Kevin The context of your quote is for mobile applications on iPhone, Android, etc. ("a complete backend solution for your mobile application") - meaning normally you'd have to provide your own stack for the mobile app to interface with for retrieving and storing data, whereas Parse provides that stack.

Comment: Parse [does do hosting](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting), but not in the way you expect (you're bound to using ExpressJS or static content).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other framework? Parse is only the data model, you need something like Laravel or Symphony to put your code together. The next step depends on the framework you choose. In fact, I'm sure there are bridge libraries for those frameworks that do everything for you.

To start though, you can just create an `index.php` file and add those lines in. This will be enough to let you test the Parse library/service.